# Displaying contents of array on multiple lines in React Native

Tags: arrays, react-native

I have an array of strings that I would like to display on screen on multiple lines in React Native for iOS. In my Text view, I currently only have the one line of code:

```
<Text style={styles.text}>
  {this.state.selectData}
</Text>
```

I would like to display 3 elements of the selectData array per line, but I can't figure out how to go about executing it.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this

```
render(){
   <View>
     {this.state.selectData.map((value, index) => {
         return (
             <Text key={index}>
                {value}
             </Text>
          );
         })
      }
     </View>
    );
}
```